# Tests failing: "after submission" -- undefined local variable or method 'submit'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm doing the exercises  for Michael Hartls Rails tutorial, chapter 7, section 7.6. I am attempting to make tests for "after submission," but get the error:

```
Failure/Error: before { click_button submit }
     NameError:
       undefined local variable or method `submit' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_4::Nested_4:0x007f8289dede70>
```

I don't know how to fix this. I have capybara installed, and all of my other tests work.

Any suggestions?

[Here is a link to the chapter](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-up#sec-signup_success)

and my code for rspec:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "UserPages" do
  subject { page }

  describe "profile page" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before { visit user_path(user) }

    it { should have_content(user.name) }
    it { should have_title(user.name) }
  end


  describe "signup page" do
    before { visit signup_path }

    it { should have_content('Sign up') }
    it { should have_title(full_title('Sign up'))}
  end 

  describe "signup" do

    before { visit signup_path }

    let(:submit) { "Create my account" }

    describe "with invalid information" do
      it "should not create a user" do
        expect { click_button submit }.not_to change(User, :count)
      end
    end

    describe "with valid information" do
      before do
        fill_in "Name",         with: "Example User"
        fill_in "Email",        with: "user@example.com"
        fill_in "Password",     with: "foobar"
        fill_in "Confirmation", with: "foobar"
      end

      it "should create a user" do
        expect { click_button submit }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
      end
    end
  end

  describe "after submission" do
    before { visit signup_path }
    before { click_button submit }

    it { should have_title('Sign up') }
    it { should have_content('error') }
  end
end
```

Comment: Please increase the details in this question. Like a link to the chapter some more of the code. It's a little vague.

Answer (score 1):

Per other questions about this stretch of Hartl's book, are you missing a

```
let(:submit) { "Sign up" }
```

?

And you should not be learning Rails by learning Capybara -> Cucumber, but that's the fashion these days...

Comment: I have let(:submit) { "Create my account" }

Comment: Put a breakpoint on `click_button submit` (or put a `sleep 100` above it), run to it, and look at the browser. Does it have a button with exactly that text? And you're gonna have to post your `<form>`, too...